# Broker Service Sending Queues Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, service-broker

I am implementing many SSB working on two different instances. They are data push pattern based on asynchronous triggers.

My SQL Info is as shown below: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.2500.0 Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 10.50.2500.0 Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514 Microsoft MSXML 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421 Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.5448 Operating System 6.1.7601

I noticed something seems strange all my sending queues are filled with messages from type
http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog

For sure it'll impact on queue performance and I've to get rid of this messages.

1- Should I assign a reader to the sending queue to end this messages?

2- Or there is something wrong I do at the receiving side while ending conversations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Broker messages as designed right now are always dialogs, which means there are always two participants in the conversation.  When one side of the conversation finishes, it calls [END CONVERSATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177521.aspx), which sends an EndDialog message type to the other participant in the dialog.  Those messages should be processed, if for no other reason than to make sure they're not taking up space.  You can create an activation stored procedure on the queue to process these.  That way, it happens automagically and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: And won't an activation procedure on the sending queue effect the sending performance?

Comment: I don't see why it would aside from minimal resource consumption (i.e. disk, cpu).  I do emphasize minimal here; if all you're doing is calling END CONVERSATION at the initiator, this should be trivial. But don't take my word for it: write it up and see how it goes for you. A couple of tips: 1) have only one activation sproc active at a time. 2) write the sproc such that it does a receive until the queue is empty (i.e. process more than one message).